# Is there a way to map user entered words (with typos) to a list of standard words?

Tags: nlp, k-means, supervised-learning

Now I have a data set where there's a column of standard words and a column for user entered words, now for example if the standard word is "Heinz Ketchup" and the user's column is "heinz ketchup", "heinz", "heinzketchup", "heinz sauce", something like these; how do I map the user entered words to the standard word?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want is to transfer the data set format from

| standard words | user words |
| --- | --- |
| "Heinz Ketchup" | "heinz ketchup", "heinz", "heinzketchup", "heinz sauce" |
| ... | ... |

to

| user words | standard words |
| --- | --- |
| "heinz ketchup" | "Heinz Ketchup" |
| "heinz" | "Heinz Ketchup" |
| "heinzketchup" | "Heinz Ketchup" |
| "heinz sauce" | "Heinz Ketchup" |
| ... | ... |

Suppose you have preprocessed the dataset into a dict in python, then you can get your map with code like this.

```py
dataset = {"Heinz Ketchup": ["heinz ketchup", "heinz", "heinzketchup", "heinz sauce"]}

data_map = {}

for k, v in dataset.items():
    for name in v:
        data_map.update({name: k})
    
print(data_map)
# {'heinz ketchup': 'Heinz Ketchup', 'heinz': 'Heinz Ketchup', 'heinzketchup': 'Heinz Ketchup', 'heinz sauce': 'Heinz Ketchup'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very helpful. Although I have one more question, I can only make a dict of terms that I have available but what if a user enters something new apart from what's in the dict? How can I still be able to tweak the code to recognize what is said (like just 'heinz' or 'HEINZ') and map it to the standard column ('Heinz Ketchup')?

Comment: Edit: And am sorry if am not being clear, but by mapping I mean display the standard word instead of the user entered word (replace it essentially) when recognized which standard word the user entered word corresponds/is similar to.

Comment: In most cases, with the dict, you can search with user's enter as key and get the value(standard word). To deal with new user words, you might want to preprocess the input string, such as converting to same letter case, in order to get a match. If user words don't match exactly existing ones, like that user may misspell a word, you can try edit distance to expand your search, such as Levenshtein distance(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Anyway, you can step-by-step optimize your application.

Comment: Thaks you so much i get it now.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to improve the matching rate but it will depend on how accurate it needs to be and how much work you are willing to put into it.

1.) You could start with something like Fuzzy Matching, e.g. https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz, which is basically a modified version of a character-level Levenshtein method string matching, see e.g. https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.metrics.distance.html#nltk.metrics.distance.edit_distance. This basically counts how many characters you have to change, move, remove or add to transform one string into the other one. You could calculate this edit_distance of a user entry with each standard word and pick the one with the lowest distance. Of course this will work great for stuff like `hienzketchup` --> `heinz ketchup` but will also return misleading results such as `mouse` --> `house`.

2.) You could use a database for synonyms such as [NLTKs Wordnet](https://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) and try to match words based on whether they are synonyms of each other/parts of n-grams are synonyms.

3.) You could use a neural model for sentence similarity such as the ones available in the [sentence-transformers package](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers), for example https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/bert-base-nli-mean-tokens. There are [quite a lot of models](https://huggingface.co/models?pipeline_tag=sentence-similarity&sort=downloads) for this. As the name says they are mostly for determining if sentences are similar rather than words/phrases, so they might not be optimal for your task. You could calculate the similarity between inputs and determine the highest probability match. Of course this approach will require significantly more computing power than the other approaches. You can pre-calculate the standard names vector representations so that you only have to calculate the inputs representation and then search for the most similar vector. Check out this example:

[image]

Comment: What if a user enters a word that's not in the words list/dict? I was thinking that the second word might be different for every user (ex: 'heinz' would be similar but the following word entered could be ketchup, or sauce or tomato ketchup, etc.,), is there a model where I could train it to recognize the key word 'Heinz' and no matter what follows next it just replaces the user entered word with the standard word 'Heinz Ketchup'.